# Use Moq To Override System.Configuration values in C# Test

Tags: c#, automated-tests, moq

I've been given the task of adding tests to some pre-existing code.  We're trying to keep refactoring to a minimum, so these tests are often a combination of unit / integration tests.

We're also using Moq on this project, which I'm learning on the fly.

My question is, how can I use Moq to override the System.Configuration values (EmailFrom, EmailTo, etc.) in SendEmail below, so I don't have to constantly babysit the System.Configuration values in all our tests System.Configuration Files?   I just want to test we execute the Email.send code

```
    public clas EmailLogging
    {
       public void SendEmail(string error}
            {
               string EmailFrom = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["EmailFrom"].ToString();
               string EmailTo = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["EmailTo"].ToString();
               string errorLogLocation = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ErrorLogLocation"].ToString();
               ...
               using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
                {
                   client.Send(mailMessage);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I use Moq to override the System.Configuration values

Moq does not have the ability to

> *override the System.Configuration values*

Option 1

Set the value in the *app.config* of the test project as that would be the context under which the test will be run.

Advantage: No need to refactor code.

Disadvantage:  have to constantly babysit the System.Configuration values in all our tests System.Configuration Files.

Option 2

Refactor the code to be more SOLID and not rely on implementation concerns

```
public interface IConfigurationSettings {
    string AppSettings[string key] { get; }
}

public interface ISmtpClient: IDisposable {
    void Send(Message message);
}

public interface IEmailLogging  {
    void SendEmail(string error);
}

public class EmailLogging: IEmailLogging {
    private readonly IConfigurationSettings ConfigurationSettings;
    private readonly ISmtpClient client;

    public EmailLogging (IConfigurationSettings settings,  ISmtpClient client) {
        this.ConfigurationSettings = settings;
        this.client = client;
    }

    public void SendEmail(string error) {
       string EmailFrom = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["EmailFrom"];
       string EmailTo = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["EmailTo"];
       string errorLogLocation = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ErrorLogLocation"];

       //...

       client.Send(mailMessage);            
    }
}
```

This will allow for separation of concerns and also individual implementations to be tested in isolation without knock on effects.

Classes that depend on `EmailLogging` can now depend on its abstraction and replace it as needed when testing to confirm that `SendEmail` was invoked.